# Unable to locate PHP defines for MySQL error numbers

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-error-1062

In my HTML code there's a select with options and a button that opens a dialog to allow the user to add to the options list [via DB/PHP/jQuery].

In the case where they enter an option that already exists in the DB, I want to catch the `MySQL Duplicate Key` error and use it to trigger code that finds the Option that matches what the User entered, and selects it for them.

`mysqli::$errno returns 1062`, and my code works great when I use the raw number.

But what if that number changes in some future update?  I would rather use a define provided by the PHP installation.

The PHP Manuel hints at such a define:

> Client error message numbers are listed in the MySQL errmsg.h header
>   file, server error message numbers are listed in mysqld_error.h. In
>   the MySQL source distribution you can find a complete list of error
>   messages and error numbers in the file Docs/mysqld_error.txt.

I found the 'mysqld_error.txt' document which has the following define:

```
#define ER_DUP_ENTRY 1062
```

There is also the following document: **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html** which has the same define.

But, when I try using this in my PHP code I get a "**Use of undefined constant ER_DUP_ENTRY - assumed 'ER_DUP_ENTRY'**" notice.  I even tried **mysqli::ER_DUP_ENTRY**.

Anyone knows a way to do this without using the numeric value?

Comment: you can define them yourself.

Comment: That still doesn't take care of the case where the number changes in some future release.

Comment: that should only happen rarely.

Comment: Not acceptable -- I want this to be immune to such things.  I mean, who would release code with such vulnerabilities?!

Comment: you could do everything in a sproc and normalize it to what you want.

Comment: Whew...been awhile.  But good idea!

Comment: and how did you use it in your code, you didnt show that

Comment: Following a mysqli INSERT query:

`if (db_res->errno == 1062)
{
    throw new DupEntryException()
}`

Then I catch the exception in an AJAX handler file [the file that called the function that executed the query] and `echo json_encode(array('dup_entry_error'=>1))`and then, in the AJAX 'success' clause, I use jQuery to select the Option that corresponds to the value that caused the mySQL Duplicate Entry error.